# group and filter JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, grouping

I have to group this JSON by artist and get the sumatory of total listeners per artist. Once this is done I need to get the most listened artist and show h the songs. What would be the most efficient way? I've tryed several ways but can't get it. Is there any JS function to do it?

This is the JSON:

```
[
    {
        "name": "The Less I Know the Better",
        "duration": "0",
        "listeners": "439958",
        "mbid": "",
        "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Tame+Impala/_/The+Less+I+Know+the+Better",
        "artist": {
            "name": "Tame Impala",
            "mbid": "63aa26c3-d59b-4da4-84ac-716b54f1ef4d",
            "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Tame+Impala"
        },
        "@attr": {
            "rank": "0"
        },
        "genre": "reggae"
    },
    {
        "name": "Creep",
        "duration": "239",
        "listeners": "1647583",
        "mbid": "d11fcceb-dfc5-4d19-b45d-f4e8f6d3eaa6",
        "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Radiohead/_/Creep",
        "artist": {
            "name": "Radiohead",
            "mbid": "a74b1b7f-71a5-4011-9441-d0b5e4122711",
            "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Radiohead"
        },
        "@attr": {
            "rank": "1"
        },
        "genre": "jazz"
    }
]
```

This JSON file it's an example, the real one is more than 800 lines long. I've tried doing a list of artists but then I can not sum the total listeners for each song of each artists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `reduce()` the array into a `Map` which makes accumulating duplicates straightforward. You can also just have a running tally of listeners thus avoiding a second iteration.

The result is a `Map` of the shape:

```
{
  "Artist1": {
    "songs": [
      {...},
      {...}
    ]
    "listeners": 0
  },
  "Artist2": {
    "songs": [
      {...},
      {...}
    ]
    "listeners": 0
  }
  ...
}
```

```js
const songs = [
    {
        "name": "The Less I Know the Better",
        "duration": "0",
        "listeners": "439958",
        "mbid": "",
        "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Tame+Impala/_/The+Less+I+Know+the+Better",
        "artist": {
            "name": "Tame Impala",
            "mbid": "63aa26c3-d59b-4da4-84ac-716b54f1ef4d",
            "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Tame+Impala"
        },
        "@attr": {
            "rank": "0"
        },
        "genre": "reggae"
    },
    {
        "name": "Creep",
        "duration": "239",
        "listeners": "1647583",
        "mbid": "d11fcceb-dfc5-4d19-b45d-f4e8f6d3eaa6",
        "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Radiohead/_/Creep",
        "artist": {
            "name": "Radiohead",
            "mbid": "a74b1b7f-71a5-4011-9441-d0b5e4122711",
            "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Radiohead"
        },
        "@attr": {
            "rank": "1"
        },
        "genre": "jazz"
    },
    {
        "name": "Go to Sleep",
        "duration": "239",
        "listeners": "16583",
        "mbid": "d11fcceb-dfc5-4d19-b45d-f4e8f6d3eaa6",
        "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Radiohead/_/Go to Sleep",
        "artist": {
            "name": "Radiohead",
            "mbid": "a74b1b7f-71a5-4011-9441-d0b5e4122711",
            "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Radiohead"
        },
        "@attr": {
            "rank": "3"
        },
        "genre": "jazz"
    }
]

const byArtist = songs.reduce((acc, song) => {
  const artistName = song.artist.name;
  const match = acc.get(artistName);
  if (match) {
    match.songs.push({...song});
    match.listeners += parseInt(song.listeners);
  } else {
    acc.set(artistName, {songs: [{...song}], listeners: +song.listeners});
  }
  return acc;
}, new Map);

console.log(Object.fromEntries(byArtist));
```

**Explanation**

You can read up on [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for further insight.

```
const byArtist = songs.reduce((acc, song) => {
  // get the artist name from the current song object
  const artistName = song.artist.name;
  // try to get the element referenced by artistName,
  // returns undefined if we haven't added that artist yet
  // otherwise it returns the object holding "songs" and "listeners"
  const match = acc.get(artistName);
  if (match) {
    // if match is truthy (successfully retrieved an entry)
    // push a copy of the song into the "songs" array
    match.songs.push({...song});
    // increment the listener count by the songs listeners
    match.listeners += parseInt(song.listeners);
  } else {
    // else set a new key: value pair useing artistName as the key
    // and creating a new object contianing "songs" and "listeners"
    acc.set(artistName, {songs: [{...song}], listeners: +song.listeners});
  }
  // return the mutated accumulator for the next iteration to use.
  return acc;
}, new Map); // this initializes the accumulator as a new Map object

// creates an Object from the Map so that it can be logged easily
console.log(Object.fromEntries(byArtist));
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was trying, but how you did it? I copied your code and works perfect but I don't undrstand how or why

Comment: Glad it helped. I can annotate the snippet if it would be useful.

Comment: it would be very useful to me if you could do it. I'm just starting with coding and everything helps me to learn and improve

Comment: added an annotated version at the end of the answer.

Comment: thank you very much I will study it and try to improve it :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
const json = `
[{
        "name": "The Less I Know the Better",
        "duration": "0",
        "listeners": "439958",
        "mbid": "",
        "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Tame+Impala/_/The+Less+I+Know+the+Better",
        "artist": {
            "name": "Tame Impala",
            "mbid": "63aa26c3-d59b-4da4-84ac-716b54f1ef4d",
            "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Tame+Impala"
        },
        "@attr": {
            "rank": "0"
        },
        "genre": "reggae"
    },
    {
        "name": "Creep",
        "duration": "239",
        "listeners": "1647583",
        "mbid": "d11fcceb-dfc5-4d19-b45d-f4e8f6d3eaa6",
        "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Radiohead/_/Creep",
        "artist": {
            "name": "Radiohead",
            "mbid": "a74b1b7f-71a5-4011-9441-d0b5e4122711",
            "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Radiohead"
        },
        "@attr": {
            "rank": "1"
        },
        "genre": "jazz"
    },
    {
        "name": "Other song of Radiohead for example",
        "duration": "239",
        "listeners": "1647583",
        "mbid": "d11fcceb-dfc5-4d19-b45d-f4e8f6d3eaa6",
        "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Radiohead/_/Creep",
        "artist": {
            "name": "Radiohead",
            "mbid": "a74b1b7f-71a5-4011-9441-d0b5e4122711",
            "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Radiohead"
        },
        "@attr": {
            "rank": "1"
        },
        "genre": "jazz"
    }
]`

const artists = {};
for (const song of JSON.parse(json)) {
    if (artists[song.artist.name]) {
    artists[song.artist.name].listeners += parseInt(song.listeners, 10);
    artists[song.artist.name].songs.push(song.name);
  } else {
    artists[song.artist.name] = {
      listeners: parseInt(song.listeners, 10),
      songs: [song.name],
    };
  }
}
console.log(artists);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution this works perfectly but I don't get how are you doing it could you provide me some more information?